# Can I create multiple products with one Shopify API call or CSV import?

Tags: node.js, shopify

Is there any way to create and update products programmatically with csv import or by api calls ?

I am using Nodejs for the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create multiple products in a single shopify api call [[Refer this]](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product). But, yes you can import multiple products by uploading csv file from store admin panel [[Refer this]](https://help.shopify.com/manual/products/import-export/import-products).

**EDIT:**   You cannot import csv programatically.

Comment: what about this app https://apps.shopify.com/syncee-1. How they did it, have you got any info?

Comment: No, I haven't used this app. But as per my experience, they have simply provided upload functionality identical to shopify import, but the benefit of this app is that it supports multiple file formats where as shopify supports only csv. In the backend they are sending individual call for each products.


EDIT: They are allowing you to upload file in their specified format, in backend they are converting it into json and then sending individual call for each product.

Comment: It has not been written anywhere that you can not add multiple products through shopify product's POST api. I have never tried multiple addition but I am sure it will work if you send in proper data array for multiple products.

Comment: @DebashisDash... As per the documentation provided by Shopify, you cannot create multiple products in single POST api call. But still, if you know something about this or if you have read it somewhere please post it over here, even I am very eager to see this happening.